# How to make a panel disappear?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I would like to make a panel look like a `ChoiceDialog`.

Let's say a have a panel like this:

```
Panel[Column[{Style["What's the gender?", FontFamily -> "Calibri", 
    FontSize -> 14], PopupMenu[Dynamic[x], optionsGender], " ", 
   Style["What's the academic title?", FontFamily -> "Calibri", 
    FontSize -> 14], PopupMenu[Dynamic[y], optionsTitle], 
   Button["Yeah!", Print[x, " ", y]]}]]
```

After clicking the button, I want to make the whole panel disappear and only leave the print in the output. Does anyone know how to do that? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does a targeted overwrite of just the `Panel`...well, technically, of the `DynamicModuleBox` with which I'm wrapping the `PanelBox`:

```
DynamicModule[{box}, 
 Panel[Column[{Style["What's the gender?", FontFamily -> "Calibri", 
     FontSize -> 14], PopupMenu[Dynamic[x], optionsGender], " ", 
    Style["What's the academic title?", FontFamily -> "Calibri", 
     FontSize -> 14], PopupMenu[Dynamic[y], optionsTitle], 
    Button["Yeah!", NotebookWrite[box, ToBoxes@Row[{x, RawBoxes@" ", y}]]]}]], 
 Initialization :> (box = EvaluationBox[])]
```

So, the idea is that I'm getting the `BoxObject` which corresponds to the outer `DynamicModuleBox`.  Then, I can pass that to `NotebookWrite`.  This allows me to overwrite the box regardless of what's inside of, and it works without changing the selection.

It does, however, have the side effect of turning the Output cell into an Input cell (assuming this was in an Output cell to begin with).  If that's an issue, then you can add this to the `DynamicModule`'s initialization:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], CellEditDuplicate] = False;
```

Comment: this is a really useful example for the use of `EvaluationBox`, which I think I just start to appreciate, so thanks for sharing. One thing I think should be noted is that it won't work with  the free CDF Player, most probably because of the `NotebookWrite` (?). As that use case seems to be closer to `Dynamic` functionality than to programmatically edit notebooks, do you think there is a chance that WRI will allow `NotebookWrite` in CDF Player when the first argument is a box in future versions?

Comment: @AlbertRetey Probably not since it would be hard to prevent users from creating notebooks using FreePlayer. In this case `PaneSelector` should be a good enough alternative.

Answer (score 4):

When clicked, the panel is replaced by the output.

```
DynamicModule[{output, x, y},
 output = Panel@Column@{
     "What's the gender?",
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[x], {"Male", "Female", Indeterminate}], 
     Spacer@10,
     "What's the academic title?", 
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[y], {None, "MSc", "PhD", All}],
     Button["Yeah!", output = Row@{x, " ", y}]};
 Dynamic@output]
```

Comment: This is also a nice option for this. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

What about a dialog box outside the current notebook?

```
DialogInput[
 Column[{Style["What's the gender?", FontFamily -> "Calibri", 
    FontSize -> 14], PopupMenu[Dynamic[x], optionsGender], " ", 
   Style["What's the academic title?", FontFamily -> "Calibri", 
    FontSize -> 14], PopupMenu[Dynamic[y], optionsTitle], 
   Button["Yeah!", DialogReturn[Row[{x, " ", y}]]]}]]
```

This seems to do the same as your panel, except the panel is outside the notebook, and it closes upon the press of the button.  See the documentation for  [`DialogInput`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DialogInput.html) and [`DialogReturn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DialogReturn.html).

Comment: I didn't realize that there is a DialogInput. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
Button["Yeah!", NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]]; Print[x, " ", y]]
```

Comment: +1 Just to spell it out, OP can keep the panel and use this method, by just replacing `Print[x, " ", y]` in the original code with `Print[x, " ", y]; NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]]`